# Connect to microsoft virtual machnine with Clion and debug `xv6` with `GDB`

Tags: gdb, virtual-machine, clion

I have a virtual machine in Microsoft Azure which runs Linux, and has the code of the `xv6 operating system`.

I want to debug it on my (Windows) computer. How can I connect to to the VM and the GDB/CGDB with my `Clion`?

I tried to add a `Remote Host` configuration in `Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains` and managed to connect to the VM, but it `Clion` requires a path to `CMake` and the compilers, and I (and `Clion`) can't find it, and get errors.

[image]

This is the error details (appears when I click `more...`):
[image]

Comment: `/usr/bin/cmake` is default path where CLion tries to find CMake executable. Please specify correct path to CMake on your remote machine.